# Size of Class with virtual inheritnce

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I was trying the below program on virtual inheritance  with the https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler ..

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ABase{ 
        int iMem; 
}; 
 
class BBase : public virtual ABase { 
        int iMem; 
}; 
 
class CBase : public virtual ABase { 
        int iMem; 
}; 
 
class ABCDerived : public BBase, public CBase { 
        int iMem; 
}; 

int main()
{
    cout << "Int is :" << sizeof(int) <<endl;
    cout << "Abase is :" << sizeof(ABase) << endl;
    cout << "Abase is :" << sizeof(BBase) << endl;
    cout << "Abase is :" << sizeof(CBase) << endl;
    cout << "Abase is :" << sizeof(ABCDerived) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The sizes of the ABase, BBase, CBase and ABCDerived are 4, 16, 16 and 40 respectively.

Normally from what i read i expect BBase and CBase to be 12 Bytes (8 bytes for the two int variables and 4 bytes for the vPtr). But i get 16, even if i assume that vPtr is using 8 Bytes, howcome ABCDerived is of 40 bytes size?

The OnlineGBD tool claims to use the G++/C++ compiler.

I know similar questions have been asked in this forum previously, but i am not able to understand this size calculation.

Comment: One word: *padding*.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `#pragma pack(1)` to remove padding so there's less room for confusion, consider:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#pragma pack(1)

class ABase{ 
        int iMem; 
}; 
 
class BBase : public virtual ABase { 
        int iMem; 
}; 
 
class CBase : public virtual ABase { 
        int iMem; 
}; 
 
class ABCDerived : public BBase, public CBase { 
        int iMem; 
}; 

int main()
{
    cout << "void* is :" << sizeof(void*) << endl;
    cout << "Int is :" << sizeof(int) <<endl;
    cout << "Abase is :" << sizeof(ABase) << endl;
    cout << "Bbase is :" << sizeof(BBase) << endl;
    cout << "Cbase is :" << sizeof(CBase) << endl;
    cout << "ABCDerived is :" << sizeof(ABCDerived) << endl;
}
```

This will give you output:

```
void* is :8
Int is :4
Abase is :4
Bbase is :16
Cbase is :16
ABCDerived is :32
```

`Bbase` and `Cbase` contain:

- an `Abase` virtual base (4 bytes)
- a pointer to their `Abase` virtual base (8 bytes)
- their own `int` member (4 bytes)

total = 16 bytes

ABCDerived contains:

- a `Bbase` base (16 bytes)
- a `Cbase` base (which just needs to store the `int` member + a pointer to the existing `Abase` virtual base inherited through `Bbase` = 4 + 8 = 12 bytes)
- their own `int` member (4 bytes)

total = 32 bytes

Comment: So ABCDerived will have two pointers to Abase;s virtual Base (one via BBase and one via CBase)??

Comment: @ArunKalirajaBaskaran yes